# Where does the hero go in Central London in a Nuclear strike?

Tags: science-based, underground, nuclear-weapons

Let me set the scene.

It’s 1994, the cold war is nearing it’s end. Regardless of the fact that the Soviet union is breaking up, a high-ranking general in the Red Army decides this is the perfect opportunity to launch a nuclear strike at western capitals.

John Smith is walking around on his lunch break somewhere between Trafalgar Square and Covent Garden, when the news reaches his ears that the Soviets have launched a 2 Megaton ICBM at Central London!
Now, if John is going to survive the blast, he will either have to get as far away from the blast zone as possible, or he will have to go deep underground, such as into an Underground station, then either walk out of the fallout zone or catch a Tube train to the suburbs where he could at least leave the city. Regardless, at most he has 5-7 minutes at most before the nuke hits the city!

My question is, assuming roughly where our hero, John, is in central London, could he go into a deep underground train station, such as Covent Garden tube station or any other suggested underground location, in order to escape the intense heat and blast from an airburst 2 Megaton Nuclear ICBM aimed at Central London in 1994?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_deep-level_shelters

Comment: Nearest one of which is the Kingsway tunnels which appear to be currently privately owned and would likely involve a 7 minute mile run to get there; no direct tube route unfortunately :)

Comment: You're looking for somewhere that can withstand >20psi of overpressure as, given how central Covent Garden is, the blast is practically overhead. That pressure demolishes concrete structures, so you need to be entombed from it. Some bank vaults have survived a blast so..that maybe? Might struggle to get out afterwards as the surrounding bank will come down on it. Definitely curious if someone comes up with something creative here.

Comment: It looks like you're asking for facts about the real world rather than creating a fictional world. This seems like more of a history question than a worldbuilding one.

Comment: I agree with @sphennings. This is storybuilding as it depends too much on (a) where the bomb goes off (in three dimensions), (b) the weather, (c) where the hero is, (d) whether or not the hero knows about the locations, (d) how long the hero has to react, etc. etc. etc. Worst of all, [you're hero's dead anyway](http://www.shoppbs.pbs.org/wgbh/amex/bomb/sfeature/1mtblast.html) unless either he/she or the bomb are nowhere near central London.

Comment: If it’s an air burst then it will normally be high enough to leave heavy shelters intact, relying on heat and pressure to only kill the population. Lower air bursts are unproductive as they have a small - albeit devastating -  range. I think a simple emergency response map of London can quickly find your public bomb shelter. Just find one built before 1994

Comment: I like your question, but if you're asking for a purely factual answer I'm not sure it's Worldbuilding. If you were instead to ask "How can my hero survive a nuclear strike on central London ca. 1994", you might open yourself up to more creative suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

**The river.**

[image: thames]

Your hero only has a minute or two.  He goes down to the river.  He flips a
little boat over or gets underneath a double hulled tour boat.  The flash does not hurt him under there and he has the shadow of the riverbank as well.  He can dive deeper to escape the wind that follows.

Plus he climbs out right after the bomb goes off.  This will make a more interesting story than being trapped underground.

Comment: Water being non-compressible (unlike the squishy human body) is _absolutely deadly_ in this way. The concrete destroying force of a nearby exploding nuke pushes the water surface and in short it ends badly for the hero :)

Comment: Mark Rober demonstration of why being in water during any sort of blast is a bad idea: https://youtu.be/W4DnuQOtA8E?t=170

Comment: Peoples, peoples. The nuke is in the air and you are in the water!  The incompressibility of the water protects you.  Read:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109888/would-being-underwater-help-survive-a-nuclear-bomb

Comment: The accepted answer there doesn't touch on the pressure wave much; the second answer covers it in more detail :) A nuke near overhead (Covent Garden is pretty much in the middle of the blast zone) is going to give the water an extreme push of 20psi or more, so even if 50% of that energy is reflected, it'll still be pretty deadly.